# Change Background and Text Color

Tags: css

I would like to make number 1 to have blue background and red text but this code doesn't work. What am I missing?

Thanks!

```css
#testtest
{
background-color: white;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #DDDDDD; 
text-align: center;
line-height:35px;
}


#testtest span.saa
{
color: yellow;

background.color: #F0F0FF;
padding: 8.25px;
margin-left: 5px;
}


#testtest span.sss
{
color: red;

background-color: blue;
padding: 8.25px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testtest" >

 <span class="sss">1</span>
 <span class="saa">2</span>
 <span class="saa">3</span>
 <span class="saa">26</span>
 <span class="saa">-&gt;</span>
     
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon `:` after sss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unwanted colon after span.sss! try:

```
#testtest span.sss
{
    color: red;

    background: blue;
    padding: 8.25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just do: .sss:
{
 color: red;
 background: blue;
 padding: 8.25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

Comment: yep...just remove the colon

Comment: Know it works with red color but it doesnot work for the class "saa"

Comment: What happens if you do .sss instead of #testtest span.sss

Comment: I've just spotted another problem in your css - if this is in your actual code it may be causing other rules not to work - background.color: #F0F0FF; in the span.saa rule needs to be changed to background-color. change . to -

Comment: Just spotted your edited comment. If the color for class saa is not working. It is because you have background.color instead of background-color. Change this and it will work.